# fallback intent not invoked from Carousel (Actions on Google)

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am connecting Actions on Google (on my Android) to my webhook via API.AI

When a user orders, say pizza online, API.AI creates a fallback intent and the webhook sends a json with Carousel.

This works fine. If user clicks on Carousel item, the response is sent to webhook too.

I am responding to that click by asking "How many pizzas" and use a suggestion chip.

However, no fallback intent is activated in API.AI and the app crashes.

Earlier, I was giving a simple text response to carousel select "Thanks for the order" and it was working.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

I realize that the problem is not in API.AI or fallback intent but in JSON I am sending. If I reply to user's selection in Carousel with a simple text/speech response it works. It also works if I send a Carousel chip again. However, if I try to send a list or card, it crashes. Perhaps, I don't have right json formatting for them.

If someone has any json sent by their webhook (working with API.AI) for list/suggestion chip or card, it would be very helpful!

---

@matthewayne  When I send the following as a reply (json), it works:

```
speech = "Thank you. People also looked at these:"
print(speech)
webhook_result={
    "speech": speech,
    "contextOut": [
        {
            "name": "_actions_on_google_,complementary",
            "lifespan": 100,
            "parameters": {}
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": True,
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": speech
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "suggestions": []
            },
            "systemIntent": {
                "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
                "data": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec",
                    "carouselSelect": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also populate carouselSelect with list of things in carousel. But if I change it to listSelect, and respond, it crashes.

When I say crash, it means that Google says that my app has stopped responding.

It would be very helpful to have a template or sample listResponse json.

Comment: what are you using to create webhook? share more info please

Comment: Can you explain why and when you think the fallback intent should be triggered after you ask "How many pizzas"? Usually you'd use another intent which listens for number-related phrases to process that turn of the conversation.

Comment: If you can update your question to show screen shots of the intent and the intent you think should be called when you respond to the Carousel, it would help us help you.

Comment: I added to the question itself to make it clear. It seems that the problem is not in API.AI's fallback intents but in my json formating for suggestion chip/ card/ list.

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes"?  Are there any error messages?  Can you provide more information on what happens when "it crashes"?

Comment: @matthewayne I added some description

Answer (score 0):

After a carousel response is sent to the user the next request that will be sent will likely be a list selection event.  You need to handle this either:

1. in API.AI (by creating an intent with the event `actions_intent_OPTION`, [docs here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#built-in_helper_intents))

   or
2. in your webhook using [the Google Assistant client library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) ([docs here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#handling_selected_item)).

Comment: This works but I guess my problem is different. I clarified it in the quesiton